# Cannot send mail with no "From" header ---- codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, sendmail

I am working on live server and using codeigniter 3.

i am unable to receive any mail.

When ever i run this code, i am getting the following error

Cannot send mail with no "From" header

```
        $config = array();
        $config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
        $config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
        $config['protocol']            = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
        $config['smtp_port']           = "25";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('admin@lucky.com','admin');
        $this->email->to('my@gmail.com');
        $this->email->cc('my@gmail.com'); 
        $this->email->subject('Registration Verification');
        $msg = "Thanks for signing up";
        $this->email->message($msg);   
        //$this->email->send();
         if (!$this->email->send())
        {    
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        } 
         else{echo 'success';}
```

Comment: receiving mail?? or any error

Comment: I am unable to receive any mail. and i am getting this error:
Cannot send mail with no "From" header

Comment: `$this->email->from('admin@lucky.com','admin');` remove admin and see

Comment: i tried , no errors , but not receiving any email

Comment: the problem was with my mail server, not with the code.. i sent many testing mails from a non existing email id.. so my mail service was disabled...

Answer (score 2):

here is wrong

```
$this->email->send();
if (!$this->email->send())
{    
echo $this->email->print_debugger();                
}
```

In your code you've already used $this->email->send() before using again $this->email->send() in your if statement. The library, after you send an email, clears everything. So, if you want to do something in case of error you don't do the same method twice:

try with

```
// $this->email->send(); don't do this and then the same thing!

if (!$this->email->send())
{    
echo $this->email->print_debugger();

}
```

Read [CI email](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-789.html)

Comment: i have updated  code according to you ..
now i am getting success message but i didnot get any mail

Comment: check your  $config['smtp_host']           = "localhost"; and check email in junk

Comment: After changes done in this code.. are you sure your are setting right smtp?? normally  'smtp_port' is 465 and you have used 25

Comment: check http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/how-to-send-email-using-php-codeigniter

Comment: i tried with smtp_port: 465 now

hello: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: check your smtp host its not localhost okk

Comment: in my server phpmyadmin its: Server: localhost

Comment: 3 days back the same code was working fine and i was getting mails..
but suddenly it stopped :(

Answer (score 1):

try normal mail sending function

**HTML Table format**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $to = 'mail@mail.com';//your mail
    $subject = 'Subject is here';
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border: 1px solid #000000" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= '<caption style="font-size: 18pt"><strong>Feedback from Customers (Testimonial)</strong></caption>';
    $message .= "<tr><td width='25'><strong>Name</strong> </td><td width='60'>".strip_tags($_POST['name'])."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email</strong> </td><td>" .strip_tags($_POST['mail']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Country</strong> </td><td>" .strip_tags($_POST['country']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['message']). "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Comment Activate Link</strong></td><td>" . $active. "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $headers = "Cc: info@mail.com"; // can use $headers = "From:
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
?>
```

or else

**Stranded mail Format**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $to = 'mail@mail.com';//your mail
    $subject = 'Subject is here';
    $message = 'text'; //simple para


    $headers = "Cc: info@mail.com";// can use $headers = "From:


     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Exit status code: 127
Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: shall i give your normal mailing code which is working??

Comment: if i use smpt i not getting error , sendmail show errors..
Not getting mail for smpt also

Comment: no i am not getting mail still :(
i think there is some problem with my mail server i guess

Comment: you are sending mail in localhost??

Comment: so that should be work, check your mail correct and check SPAM folder too

Comment: yes i have checked both spam and inbox .. i didnot get mail

Comment: the problem was with my mail server, not with the code..
i sent many testing mails from a non existing email id..
so my mail service was disabled...

Comment: if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it or Vote it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator as follows

```
($this->email->send())? $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Email sent successfully."): 
$this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Email not sent, there was error");
```